# Using a diode to clamp a 24V logic output to 5V

Tags: diodes, level-shifting, logic-level, diode-clamp

I have a controller board (the [Teknic ClearCore](https://www.teknic.com/files/downloads/clearcore_user_manual.pdf)) in which output signals are pulled up to 24VDC. I am trying to interface with a [TLC5947](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc5947.pdf?ts=1635770025094&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTLC5947) LED driver IC rated at 5V maximum control input voltage.

The ClearCore datasheet shows that a diode can be used when trying to keep the voltage down to 5V.

[image]

Could someone point me in the right direction with regards to how to select the best diode for the job, bearing in mind that the output signals are going to be switching at a fast rate? And I am also wondering what the benefit in using a diode over a simple voltage divider is if there's no concern about overvoltage.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

There is no best diode. I am surprised the manual even suggests this, it does not seem like a professional solution.

With a standard diode, the input voltage would exceed absolute maximum ratings of the chip.

Even if you used a schottky diode, the 10k pull-up resistor in the controller will still push about 2mA per pin to chip power supply.

If the supply of the chip does not have a load to consume much current, the 5V supply voltage can rise beyond safe limits for the chip.

I don't see how "fast" rates are you expecting to switch - a FET intended to drive moderate loads with just 10k pull-up to 24V can't switch at fast rate, it would be few kHz tops.

Answer (score 1):

[image]  (from your [link](https://www.teknic.com/files/downloads/clearcore_user_manual.pdf))

The output is current limited by 24V/ 10k for a short to gnd and a 5V clamp draws less voltage and current. So any small signal diode yet CMOS have 10k+D > 10+D clamps to each rail to further clamp the input with Sch. ESD protection diodes , they are tiny and rated for 5 mA typ.. Si diodes with almost no load will have a very low Vf.

### Recommended

It makes more sense to use the 5V logic level out for data and clock with series R to compensate for the cable impedance and low driver Vol/Iol impedance.  40 to 200 ohms typ. depends on cable type.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for kindly addressing this, but the explanation of why each type of diode wouldn't be suitable is slightly unclear to me. Could you please elaborate it a bit further?

Comment: The bigger question now seems why not use the 5V logic port with resistor ( if necessary, using cable to match impedance)  to drive the controller board. Then no clamp needed since no 24V. The diode otherwise has to clamp say 2 mA if switched, so low current, or none if CC 4~20 mA modulation.